# Received error "Value of type ... has no member 'frame'"

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

PLEASE help me with this ive tried like 50 different things on this one.

this is for a view controller for multiple pages, im pretty new to this so please if you answer try to answer as if you're teaching some one new

Comment: FYI, in the future, please include the text of the error message as well as the text of the code that generated the error. Include image if you think it's essential, but always include the text. The goal of Stack Overflow is to be a useful, searchable database of questions and answers, and if you include image without any identifiable narrative, that defeats the purpose of this site.

Comment: with the code you guys gave me now it says Value of type UIScrollView has no member contentSize

Comment: A UIViewController doesn't have a frame... but it's view does. Use self.view.frame like you did on the second one (height). You also need to add the width and height parameters.

Comment: @AleksPavlovsky - I hate to do this to you, but that's a different question. You should accept one of the answers below and then post a new question on that topic. But `UIScrollView` has (even in Swift 3) a `contentSize` property, so there's probably something curious about how `scrollView` was declared, so make sure you include its declaration in your new question. Make sure you rebuild the app, though, because sometimes errors can linger if you made and fixed other errors on the line in question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Rob. Im still having a load of issues IM really new to swift and I thought this was the best place to learn as I go. If there is a better place to ask questions for new people please let me know and Ill do that from now on. Again sorry for the very stupid questions as they are most likely too easy for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your self object doesn't directly contain the 'view' property.

fixed code:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width * 3, height: view.frame.size.height - 66)
```

Comment: with the code you gave me now it says "Value of type UIScrollView has no member contentSize"

Comment: I made a typo, try now

Comment: Youre the best thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need the frame of the VIEW

```
self.view.frame
```